# How to scroll to a child component depending on the class name of an element which is in the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a LiteratureList component which is the parent component and a Literature component (children). Depending on how many literature entries have been stored in the database, the literature component gets called a couple of times from the parent. So e.g. there are 5 literature entries in the db, there will be rendered 5 different Literature components.

After the first render, the first Literature object has a state variable `active:true`. Every other Literature object has a state variable `active:false`. I highlight the active object by coloring it in a different color. Now when I press enter, the second literature object gets set as active.

Now I've got the problem that the active object jumps out of my browser view if I press enter for e.g. 3 times because I have no window.scrollTo function so that it automatically scrolls to my active object.

This is basically my parent cocde:

```
class LiteratureList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      highlightIndex: 0,
      literatureEntries: ...get from database,
}}
....
handleEnterPress(e){
const keyCode = e.keyCode
      if (keyCode === 13) {          //enter key -> increase index of the 
                                     //item which should be 
                                     //highlighted by one -> next card will 
                                     //be highlighted
       this.setState({ highlightIndex: this.state.highlightIndex + 1 })
}
}
render()
return(
{
    this.state.literatureEntries.map((literature, index) => {
    let active = true;
    if (this.state.highlightIndex !== index) {
        active = false
    }
       return (
           <Literature literature={literature}
            active={active}/>)
   })
 }
 )
 }
```

And this is my child (Literature) component:

```
export default class Literature extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            active: props.active,
            literature: props.literature,
        } 
     }
...
render()
  return(

   <Col xs="12" key={literature._id}>
    <Card id={this.state.active ? "highlight" : null} className={this.state.active ? "highlight" : null}>
         ....some text ...
    </Card>
  </Col>
  )
}
```

I've already tried to set the ref of each Literature object in the parent and then call the scrollIntoView like this:

```
class LiteratureList extends Component{
...
handleEnterPress(e){
...
     this.active.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })          //active because I set 
        //the ref = "active" if 
        //Literature object is active 
}
...
render()
return(
... <Literature ref={() => { if (active) { return "active" } else { return "inactive" } }} 
     literature={literature} active={active}/>)
)
}
```

But with this code I'll get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing so I will try to explain what you need to do without using your code.

You will need some states and a property.

```
state = {
    currentIndex: 0, // index of the active item
    literatures: [] // the list of literatures
}

literaturesRef = [] // array of references of the Literature component
```

So you will need to render the list of literatures and set the reference for that component using the index.

```
this.state.literatures.map((literature, i) => (
    <Literature 
       ref={ref => literaturesRef[i] = ref} // correct way of setting the ref
       literature={literature} 
       active={this.state.currentIndex === i}
    />
))
```

Now when you press enter, inside `handleEnterPress`, you will access the `literaturesRef` with the `currentIndex` and call `scrollIntoView`

```
handleEnterPress = e => {
    // correctly accessing the reference of the current index
    this.literaturesRef[currentIndex].current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })          
}
```

## Edit

I was forgetting one detail. you pass the `ref` to `Literature` but inside it you need to pass that `ref` to a doom element (probably a `div`) so, when you access `this.literaturesRef[this.state.currentIndex]`, it's a doom element which will have the method `scrollIntoView` and you won't get the error you described in the comments

Comment: I declared literaturesRef=[] inside the constructor. I tried your code snippets but it's not working as I wanted. So if I do console.log(this.literaturesRef[this.state.currentIndex]) I get console logged a literature object with "{props:{...}, context:{...}, refs:{...},state:{...},...." and so on...
But when I have this code in the handleEnterPress function this.literaturesRef[this.state.currentIndex].current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })   I always get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined
"

Comment: @Till you can't and should be able to do `console.log(this.literaturesRef[this.state.currentIndex])` and get `{props:{...}, context:{...}, refs:{...},state:{...}}` this isn't how state management of react works

Comment: If you want to get `{props:{...}, context:{...}, refs:{...},state:{...}}`, you are doing something wrong. Maybe if you explain why you want to do that, I can show a way of doing what you need in another way

Comment: Actually I just console logged this.literaturesRef[this.currentIndex] because I've got the error "cannot read property scrollIntoView of undefined" and I wanted to see if something is stored in this.literaturesRef or why he was throwing this error

Comment: @Till what do you see in `this.literaturesRef[this.currentIndex]`?

Comment: What exaclty do you mean what I see in `this.literaturesRef[this.currentIndex]`?

Comment: @Till What do you see when you call `console.log(this.literaturesRef[this.currentIndex])`

Comment: when I console log `this.literaturesRef[this.currentIndex` I'll get this: [picture](https://www.directupload.net/file/d/5817/nbvhnzsr_png.html)   info: your "currentIndex" is "highlightIndex" in my code

Comment: @Till try what I added in my question. Inside `Literature`, pass `this.props.ref` to the ref of an dom element

Comment: I've tried to set `ref =this.props.ref` in the main `div` container inside `Literature` but `this.props.ref` is undefined

Comment: I've made it work but actually I have no idea why it works this way and not the other.
 `<Literature ref={ref => { this.literaturesRef[index] = ref }} pleaseWork={this.literaturesRef[index]} literature={literature}`

and then set the ref of an dom element inside `Literature` as: `<div ref={this.props.pleaseWork}> .... </div>`. But I have no idea why it works if I pass another prop variable (`pleaseWork`)  and why it hadn't worked when I tried to access the `ref` prop